# can a script change the cwd of the bash in which the script is running?

Tags: bash

Here is the scenario, I open up a terminal, and the `bash`'s `cwd` is `/home/me', like this:

```
[/home/me $] ls
a.sh
```

Now I `a.sh` in the cwd like this:

```
[/home/me $] ./a.sh
```

What I want is that, I want to change the `bash`'s `cwd` by running `a.sh`, which means after `a.sh` finishes, the `bash`'s `cwd` won't be `/home/me`,

```
[/home/other_dir $]
```

Can I do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [source](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_source.htm) command which runs in the current shell's context. So all the change done in the script will be visible in the your shell.

For example:

If the content of a.sh is: `cd /usr/bin`

then executing the following will result in change in `CWD`

`$ source a.sh`

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to run `a.sh` without forking a subshell like this:

```
. ./a.sh
```

This will make sure to run your script in current shell itself and and `change dir` command inside your script will be reflected in current shell.